# How can I prevent hardcoding of some attributes in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have following statement:

```
<font color="#2B547E">
```

Now I don't want to hard code it in my html; instead I want to apply a css class. I don't want this color for all fonts in my page, only for a specific part. I tried the following:

```
 <font class="xyz" >
```

But it's not working. I can't use a div/span as it results in a new line in my html template due to some predefined stylesheet which I can't change.

How can I move that hard coded value to css?

Comment: How can you even hope to use CSS if you're still using the `<font>` tag?

Comment: CSS and the font tag are contrasting techniques, and can therefore not be combined in one tag. Consider it somewhere around having a Depth-meter in a boat that is not a sub-marine. Either the boat is a sub-marine and uses the depth-meter, or it isn't and has no use for the depth-meter. So the font-tag cannot have a class attribute.

Comment: @Bazzz - "font-tag cannot have a class attribute" If you try it you'll see that it works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you can add a CSS class for this `<font>` element, you should be able to switch over to using a `<span>`:

HTML:

```
<span class="coloredText">text</span>
```

CSS:

```
.coloredText {
    display: inline; /* will stop spans creating a new line */
    color: #2B547E;
}
```

If you still find the span creates a line break, you can change the rule to
`display: inline !important;` - this will increase the precendence of this rule so it will take effect. I'm not sure if the use of `!important` is frowned upon by CSS-pedants, but it might help.

Comment: Good info, but indeed `!important` is frowned upon, and in theory it should be possible to create stylesheets that do not use it. However, if conditions are such that `!important` solves the issue rather than overhauling the whole system, then one should just use it. More interesting is your `display:inline` which you claim stops spans from creating new lines, but `spans` are by definition `inline` and do not create new lines. I understand your thinking here, but if all spans create new lines, something is already wrong earlier in the css and your approach is merely symptom-treating.

Comment: @Bazzz: the reason I put this is that in the question it says "I can't use a div/span as it results in a new line in my html template due to some predefined stylesheet which I can't change." I realize `span` is an inline element, but if another stylesheet (which can't be changed) has made them block elements, this will change them back.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

HTML:

```
<font class="xyz">...</font> <!-- or any other tag -->
```

CSS:

```
font.xyz {color:#2B547E;} /* or just .xyz */
```

See also: [Class and ID Selectors](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssintermediate/classid/)

Answer (score 1):

First off, use a reset css to reset all your styles to a default of your choice.

I use this one, but there are others around : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Then, write your css and use targeting to apply the styles to different elements

This link explains CSS specificity : http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='reset.css'>
<style>
#top p {
  color: blue;
}

#bottom p {
  color: red;
} 

.black {
  background: #000;
}
</style>


<div id='top'>
  <p>This text will be blue</p>
  <span class='black'>I have a black background</span>
<div>

<div id='bottom'>
  <p>This text will be red</p>
  <span class='black'>I have a black background too!</span>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination like this:

```
<div class="xyz">Your content goes here...</div>
```

and the CSS can be:

```
.xyz {display: inline; color: #2B547E;}
```

This will solve the problem of new line and also give the desired color.

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific with your selector, instead of just div, use div.class, or div.id

```
<div class="Foo">
  Bar
</div>


div.Foo {
  color:#2B547E;
  margin:0;  /* overriding the predefined styles in other sheet */
  padding:0;  /* overriding the predefined styles in other sheet */
}
```

replace margin / padding with whatever is causing the new line.

Also I'd always recommend not using style tags; such as Font.  Your Html should use declarative only tags.  Not to mention the Font tag is [deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_fonts.asp).

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="xyz">consectetur adipiscing elit.</span> Mauris ultrices arcu eu velit euismod pulvinar.</p>
```

CSS

> .xyz {
>       color: #66CD00; }

[View a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/W2mZM/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of lost as to what you can and can't do here ;) but I'll put this in incase

```
font[color="#2B547E"] {color: red;}

<p>I have following statement: <font color="#2B547E">I can't use a div/span as it results in a new line in my html template due to some predefined stylesheet which I can't change.</font></p>
```

Unfortunately **IE7** has problems with this but it does target if you use  `font[color] {color: red;}` - This will of course not enable you to specifically target by existing colors if that's what you're after - but it will target them all to bring them in line if that's all you require, a mixture of the two might provide a decent enough fallback?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be a case of CSS specificity, i cant tell from the details provided.  if your style for spans is defined through an ID such as

`#somediv span{ display:block}`

That css will overwrite something like

`span.myspan{display:inline}`

because the ID style is more specific,  you can solve this a few ways, first you can set the style inline in the html.

`<span style"display:inline; color:#2b547e;">some text</span>`

or you can make a class and use a more specific style by including the parent ID in the css

`#somediv span.myclass{display:inline}`